# Como habilitar el traspaso de palabras con Ñ y tildes con JSON en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

actualmente estoy haciendo un buscador de datos para que me autocomplete unos inputs(html) con JSON, el codigo de js es de la siguiente manera:

```
function mostrar(){

var datos = {
                "nombre_f": $("#nombre_f").val(),
            }
$.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: 'formulario/completar_formulario.php',
        data: datos,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
            //id de los inputs
            $("#mod_nombre_real").val(d[0]);
            $("#mod_departamento").val(d[1]);
            $("#mod_distrito").val(d[2]);
        }
    });
}
```

y en el php el codigo es de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("mantenimiento",$con);

  $filtro=$_POST["nombre_f"];
  $rs=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM adress WHERE id_celda LIKE '".$filtro."' order by id_unica desc ");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);

  $datos_a_enviar = array($row['nombre'],$row['departamento'],$row['distrito']);
  echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar);
  ?>
```

pero los valores que devuelvo son (kevin,LIMA,BREÑA), entonces como hay una "ñ" en regresa nada, pero cuando hago otra consulta si trae los valores normalmente(consulta que no tenga "ñ" ni tildes)... como puedo hacer para que JSON me acepte la devolucion de la letra "ñ" y tildes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo tuve el mismo problema
Lo solucione colocando el cotejamiento de la base de datos, en la conexión

`$conexion=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database)`

`mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");`

Answer (score 1):

La función `json_encode` recibe un segundo parámetro, un array de opciones, en tu caso debes utilizar `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`;

```
echo json_encode($datos_a_enviar,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Documentacion: https://www.php.net/json_encode

Edito, vi algo mas en tu codigo;

Te falta pasar tus datos a `JSON` en javascript;

```
var datos = {
                "nombre_f": $("#nombre_f").val(),
            }

datos= JSON.stringify(datos);
```

Te explico; estas intentando enviar un `JSON` pero no estas convirtiendo tus datos a este formato, simplemente lo estas pasando como objeto y esto seria un POST normal.

Comment: tambien intente con JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, pero igual no me carga el JSON

Comment: tu problema es que el `JSON` no llega al backend ?

Comment: @Kevincs7 vi algo mas en tu código y modifique mi respuesta,

Comment: claro, tengo un index.php donde tengo cajas de texto, donde se deben autocompletar(sus id los menciono en mi codigo de JS), pero no se autocompletan...

Comment: cuando añado "datos= JSON.stringify(datos);" debajo de mi codigo var datos={} , resulta que ahora no regresa ningun valor,osea los que presenten tilde y/o ñ y los que no

Comment: Deberías probar la salida en la consola del navegador, ya esto debajo de lo que te sugerí agregar `console.log(datos)`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83353/discussion-between-kevincs7-and-yo-albert).

Answer (score 0):

```
//esta funcion  convierte cadenas que tengan tildes 
//es muy bueno 




function utf8to16(str) {
    var out, i, len, c;
    var char2, char3;

    out = "";
    len = str.length;
    i = 0;
    while(i < len) {
    c = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    switch(c >> 4)
    { 
      case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
        // 0xxxxxxx
        out += str.charAt(i-1);
        break;
      case 12: case 13:
        // 110x xxxx   10xx xxxx
        char2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        out += String.fromCharCode(((c & 0x1F) << 6) | (char2 & 0x3F));
        break;
      case 14:
        // 1110 xxxx  10xx xxxx  10xx xxxx
        char2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        char3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        out += String.fromCharCode(((c & 0x0F) << 12) |
                       ((char2 & 0x3F) << 6) |
                       ((char3 & 0x3F) << 0));
        break;
    }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Amigo, explica un poco tu código y tu respuesta podría ganar tu primera medalla!